# Find Derivative using only chain rule

Tags: derivatives

How can I find derivative of $\tan\left(\sqrt{x}\right)\cdot x^4$ using only chain rule?

Comment: You mean you *do not* want to use the product rule as well?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! some notes: (1) I've edited your post. Please ensure this is the required function (you missed the right parenthesis). (2) Please clarify what is allowed. (3) In this site it is highly encouraged to show some effort regarding your questions. (4) Use MathJax for math notations.

Comment: StackTD: Yes I do not want to use product rule, only chain rule.

Comment: Galc 127: Thanks for the correction, yes this bracket was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see why you would want to avoid the product rule, but you could do the following for any product $f(x)g(x)$:
$$f(x)g(x) = e^{\ln \left( f(x)g(x) \right)} = e^{\ln f(x) + \ln g(x)}$$
The derivative then becomes, with the chain rule:
$$\left( f(x)g(x) \right)' = \left( e^{\ln f(x) + \ln g(x)}\right)' = e^{\ln f(x) + \ln g(x)} \left( \ln f(x) + \ln g(x)\right)'$$
I hope you can use the *sum rule*... For the logarithms; chain rule again:
$$\left( f(x)g(x) \right)' = \cdots = e^{\ln f(x) + \ln g(x)} \left( \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} +\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}\right)$$

Comment: Dear StackTD this is exactly what I was looking for, thanxs a lot

Comment: Alright! I guess you're not a big fan of the *product rule* then... :-). You're welcome.

Comment: As a general trick: logarithms turn products into sums...

Answer (score 0):

Here the chain rule is useful only to compute the derivative of the first factor, that is $\tan(\sqrt{x})$.

$$\left(\tan(\sqrt{x})\right)' = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \times (1+\tan^2(\sqrt{x}))$$

And then just use product rule.

Answer (score 0):

For the product you need to resort to partial derivatives,

$$d(xy)=\frac{\partial(xy)}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial(xy)}{\partial y}dy.$$

Then, using the chain rule

$$\frac{d(\tan\left(\sqrt{x}\right)\cdot x^4)}{dx}=\frac{(\partial\tan\left(\sqrt{x}\right)\cdot x^4)}{\partial \tan\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}\frac{d\tan\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}{d\sqrt x}\frac{d\sqrt x}{dx}+\frac{\partial(\tan\left(\sqrt{x}\right)\cdot x^4)}{\partial x^4}\frac{dx^4}{dx}\\
=x^4\frac1{\cos^2(\sqrt x)}\frac1{2\sqrt x}+\tan\left(\sqrt{x}\right)4x^3.$$

---

We took for granted that the power function $f_\alpha(x)=x^\alpha$ is known to have the derivative $\alpha x^{\alpha-1}$.